# What's the name of this fantasy tv show?

Tags: story-identification, tv

The show was made in the 90's, I believe, about a teen girl. Can't recall if she was an alien or just a powerful girl. Anyway, she has a stars mark on her face next to her eye (the stars shine for some reason). Could you please help me out?

Comment: was this a cartoon, or live? Possibly Jem? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jem_%28TV_series%29  http://www.youtube.com/results?q=jem&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=w1

Comment: We were thinking the same thing, @DavidStratton

Comment: Totally outrageous. Jem is her name.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be [Jem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jem_(TV_series)), perchance?

[image: Jem Logo]

- Made from 1985-1988
- Starred a girl in her teens
- When Jerrica Benson became Jem, she often had star-like makeup around her eyes